# How can i restore my S8+ to an older back-up?

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, restore

ok i have a samsung s8+, just switched from iphone. ive only had the phone a short time but needless to say it has backed up to both google and samsung accounts at least a few times if not more. i know how to restore from the most recent backup on both but i would actually like to restore from an older backup, even preview them if possible. any way I can do this ??

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that a new Back Up overstrikes the previous one. So you can only restore the latest backup.